# Content view does not show when testing in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard

I am pretty new to Objective-C and I am stuck in this part. I am trying to display the controls the textfield, label, Gradient views, and the Transfer button which are inside the content view of the cell, but it does not appear when I test it out. It only shows "1. Data to operate" twice but no content.. Can someone please help me out with this? I would appreciate it.

Below is how my ViewController looks like:

```
@implementation CNCTransfersOwnViewController{

}

//@synthesize delegate;


+ (id)instanceFromStoryboard {
    return [self instanceFromStoryboardNamed:@"Transfer"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setUpUI];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)setUpUI {
    self.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"GO TO SOMEWHERE ELSE";
}

- (NSString *)identifierForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *identifier = @"";

            identifier = @"OPERATION";

    return identifier;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(self.tableView == tableView){
        return 2;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(self.tableView == tableView){
        NSString *identifier = [self identifierForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the text you want to display in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(self.tableView == tableView){
        NSString *identifier = [self identifierForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.text = @"The text you want to display";
        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nima, thanks but I don`t really want to display a text but the controls the textfield, label, and the Transfer button which is inside the content view from the ¨dataOperarSelectedCell¨ as shown in the 2nd image..